# Склонение названия района

Tags: склонение, топонимика

Какой вариант склонения правильный или они равнозначны?
Родился в д. Алексеево Елатомского уезда, ныне Ермишинский район... или ныне Ермишинского района? В текстах встречаются оба варианта.

Comment: "Ныне" можно заменить на "сейчас". Второй вариант всё равно звучит?

Comment: Вы действительно встречали второй вариант? Если да, добавьте предложения с ним.

Comment: Г. В. Вахрушев родился в небольшой деревне Некрасовка ныне Гафурийского района нашей республики.

Comment: @user190920 Да, об этом думал, без уточнения да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более логичным выглядит первый вариант: *Родился в д. Алексеево Елатомского уезда, н**ыне Ермишинский район**...*

Почему? Это уточнение, **дополнительная** (отдельно оформленная) информация.

А если так: *Родился в д. Алексеево Елатомского уезда, ныне (в д. Алексеево) **Ермишинского района...***

Здесь дополнительная информация встраивается в **основной** текст, что и выглядит нелогично, необоснованно, да и грамматически не очень корректно.

С другой стороны, надо учитывать **контекст.** Можно предположить, что это обычные биографические данные для конкретного лица.

Comment: "С другой стороны, надо учитывать контекст. Можно предположить, что это обычные биографические данные для конкретного лица". Так и есть. Еще пример: ... род. 1923, дер. Шои Уржумского уезда Вятской губернии, ныне Лебяжский (Лебяжского?) район (района?) Кировской области - ум. 1988, Москва. Уточнение подразумевает, что административно деревня СЕЙЧАС входит в Лебяжский район, который не имеет никакого отношения к уезду.

Comment: Я думаю, что надо так ... род. 1923, дер. Шои Уржумского уезда Вятской губернии, ныне Лебяжский район  Кировской области - ум. 1988, Москва. Даже сама графика выглядит корректнее.

Comment: Спасибо, Елена!..

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ)